# Controls Inheriting Parent's Custom Drawing Code

Tags: winforms, system.drawing

I am trying to write an application that uses nested controls plus a `Control.Paint` event handler to draw a custom border. See the image below:

[image: Drawing Glitch Example]

Notice how the "About ChocoTester" and "View version..." labels, as well as the `PictureBox` containing the icon, also draw the border (and, presumably, the background color as well, although that is not as immediately visible). I have added a `Control.Paint` event handler to the outermost box *only*. However, for some reason, the child controls are inheriting the Paint event code of the parent. I have never seen Windows Forms do this before until I started work on this project.

Note that the child controls have a `BackColor` of `Transparent`. This may or may not have anything to do with the symptoms described above. Also note that *any* child control of another control where the parent has a custom `Paint` event exhibits this behavior, be they standard `Label` instances or Panels with custom drawing code of their own.

Here is a sample `Panel.Paint` handler that exhibits this problem:

```
Rectangle r = e.ClipRectangle; r.Inflate(-1, -1);
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.AliceBlue, r);
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkBlue, r);
```

Comment: share your code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this on my own end. The problem was that I was using the `PaintEventArgs.ClipRectangle` to size the drawing. If I construct a `Rectangle` manually using `Control.Width` and `Control.Height`, and use that to draw to the screen, the behavior discussed above goes away.